# multiple DHCP servers for wireless users on same subnet

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, dd-wrt

I am trying to set up 2 router in our network with following set up. 2 routers, 1 is the main router that DHCP is enabled to assign ip to all wired PCs, the other one can be assumed for guest, which is also DHCP enabled. The main one should assign IP from 192.168.1.2 to 1.253 to wired pc and the one for guest should assign ip from 192.168.2.2 to 2.254 to guest devices.

The main router uses Tomato 1.28 while the other one uses DD-WRT v24-sp2 std. After some research I know I could set it up as this way, connect LAN port on Tomato one to WAN port on DD-WRT one. So the DD-WRT one doesn't mess up the main router's DHCP service. When I was testing, a wifi user connected to the DD-WRT router, it is assigned with an ip address as 192.168.2.100 but it didnt have Internet connection. Anyone could give me some help how exactly I should configure the DD-WRT router to make it work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: was the gateway advertised via the router? did the endpoint receive the gateway address?

Comment: Yes, it is advertised via the DD-WRT router as 192.168.2.1, so is the local DNS. And the client did receive the gateway and DNS correctly, both as 192.168.2.1.

Comment: if endpoints received both an IP and a Gateway, they should.t have any problem accessing the internet. Check for DD-WRT setings. Alternatively, configure an endpoint with a static IP and gateway (hardcoded) and try to connect via the router and check if you have internet access.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't work. Do I need to do any particular set up on the main router which is running tomato? Plz be reminded that the LAN cable is plugged into the WAN port of the secondary router which is running DD-WRT.